# Industry Standard for training models?

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, scikit-learn

Training a model on a few megabytes of data is taking longer than I expected. How are people training models on datasets that go into the gigabytes and petabytes?

Are there any good resources for learning how to do these practices?

I'm currently working in a Jupyter Notebook and doing some machine learning with scikit-learn.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about your data and which algorithms you are using?

Comment: I'm working with [Kaggle's Rossman Store Data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/data) and plugging it into a  Support Vector Machine

Comment: Why are you using Support vector Machine for predicting the sales? Support vector machines is recommended to use as a classifier ,i.e, to deal with classification problem. You should start with linear regression to predict the sales as it is a continuous variable and it won't take longer time as well.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research it looks like using services like AWS, DigitalOcean, etc in combination with VirtualMachine or Docker are a starting point for doing machine learning on large datatsets.

Sources:

[Kaggle](http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/02/05/how-to-get-started-with-data-science-in-containers/)